# Parse HTML meta tags on upload to SharePoint

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, metadata

SharePoint parses and synchronizes custom document properties with SharePoint properties for MS Office documents "out of the box".

I need to configure MOSS 2007 to parse HTML meta tags and synchronize them to custom SharePoint properties in a similar fashion when HTML documents are uploaded to a library.

Meta tags in the following format

```
<meta name="foo" content="bar" >
```

I'm new to SharePoint and not sure if it is a simple configuration or if some custom code needs to be developed.

Has anyone done this (or something similar) before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an [EventHandler](http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1547) to check that metadata and make them meaningful for Sharepoint.

After create and install it, everytime you upload a file to your document library, your code takes control and handle that metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I like Rubens' answer better but there's another option... upload a Ms Word document which alows for custom properties.  These custom properties are promoted from said document in the fashion you described... from there use SharePoint's "Document Conversion" functionality to convert from Word to HTML

Once again Ruben's method is a little more realistic!

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to accomplish is exactly what occurs for Word document custom properties, but for existing HTML documents with meta tags as they are uploaded.